# Egit - commited new project to wrong repository, can not delate it

Tags: java, github, repository, egit, git-commit

I recently created new project ("`FirstSimpleWebDataBase`")  and committed it to new repo.
Today I was working on my old project ( "`BeamReinforcement`" )  and accidentally pushed whole "`firstSimpleWebDataBese`" project into it's repository.

When I check repo at Github it's shows this:

[image]

Added by accident project is grey and I would like to delete it.
I checked history in EGit but there is not such commit so I can not reverse it from eclipse. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

That gray folder is a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the parent index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))

What you can do locally is make sure that folder is removed:

- make sure to move FirstSimpleWebDatabase outside the Git repo folder
- type:

  ```
  git rm --cached FirstSimpleWebDatabase  # no trailing slash
  git add .
  git commit -m "record deletion of FirstSimpleWebDatabase gitlink"
  git push
  ```

Then you can go back to Egit and go on from there.